# c# - Recursive property set

Tags: c#, wpf, recursion, inotifypropertychanged

I have the following data structure in my WPF app

```
public interface IObject
{
    ObservableCollection<IObject> SubItems { get; set; }
    eStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public class Object : IObject
{
    private eStatus status;
    public eStatus Status
    { 
         get;
         set
         {
             status = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Status");
         }
     }
}
```

so that when the status of an IObject changes, it notifies (via NotifyPropertyChanged) the SubItems that recursively do the same

```
public void StatusChanged()
{
    // ... do something and recalculate the status looping
    // through my SubItems
    Status = newStatus;
}
```

Problem is that in the setter of my property the value is correctly set, but when the StatusChanged() of the parent object is called, when I check the Status of its SubItems (one of which, should have been just set and it is set because otherwise the PropertyChanged event would not have been fired) the Status of the checked element is not the one I expect to be!

It seems like the ObservableCollection items are not updated when I execute the code.

Comment: Where is the Status getting updated to cause the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: The subscription code to the event would help too.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 when I add a IObject to the SubItems, before adding the new object to the list, I subscribe the parent method (this.StatusChanged) to the new element PropertyChanged.

Comment: Why are you setting the Status within the StatusChanged event? Surely this is an infinite loop? Are you meant to be setting the Status of the SubItems instead?

Comment: Please can you post the code you use to subscribe the parent method to the child method, the whole `StatusChanged()` method and the whole `OnCollectionChanged` implementation? Without those details it's difficult to help you

Comment: @Cognition I'm checking the status of the SubItems to set the status of "this". So that's not an infinite loop.